# Python w/Google Drive API

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am trying to transfer a file to my google drive using the API and a service account. When I run it, I get a file ID, but the file doesn't actually show up in my drive, so I have no idea where the file is actually going.

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

#Set up a credentials object I think
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('service_account.json', ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])

#Now build our api object, thing
drive_api = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

file_name = "test.html"
print "Uploading file " + file_name + "..."

#We have to make a request hash to tell the google API what we're giving it
body = {'name': file_name, 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'}

#Now create the media file upload object and tell it what file to upload,
#in this case 'test.html'
media = MediaFileUpload('test.html', mimetype = 'text/html')

#Now we're doing the actual post, creating a new file of the uploaded type
fiahl = drive_api.files().create(body=body, media_body=media).execute()

#Because verbosity is nice
print "Created file '%s' id '%s'." % (fiahl.get('name'), fiahl.get('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

From your sample script, I thought that Python Quickstart is easy for you to understand. So it uses Python Quickstart at (https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python).

1. Please carry out Step 1 and Step 2 at Python Quickstart.
2. Please modify the sample script at Python Quickstart as follows.

**From :**

1.

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'
```

2.

```
results = service.files().list(
    pageSize=10,fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
items = results.get('files', [])
if not items:
    print('No files found.')
else:
    print('Files:')
    for item in items:
        print('{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
```

**To :**

1.

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
```

2.

```
f = 'test.html'
mime = 'text/html'
body = {
    'name': f,
    'mimeType': mime
    # 'parents': ## folderID ##, # If you want to upload file under folder, please use this.
}
results = service.files().create(
    body=body,
    media_body=MediaFileUpload(f, mimetype=mime, resumable=True)
).execute()
print(results)
```

When the file was uploaded, following JSON can be obtained. And you can see the file on Google Drive.

```
{
  "mimeType": "text/html",
  "name": "test.html",
  "id": "#####",
  "kind": "drive#file"
}
```