# Upload files in base64 to google drive using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-drive-api, drive

I'm looking for a code to upload files to google drive using python. Currently I have only the code for authenticacion.

**Code V1**

```
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials      
    from httplib2 import Http

    #Authentication
    scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('config/key_file.json', scopes)
    http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())      
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http_auth)

    folder_id = 'XXXYYYZZZ'
```

Is it possible? Any idea? thanks

**Code V2**

```
    from apiclient import discovery
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
    from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
    from httplib2 import Http

    #Authentication
    scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('config/key_file.json', scopes)
    http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())      
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http_auth)

    folder_id = 'XXXYYYZZZ'

    f = 'test.html'
    mime = 'text/html'
    body = {
        'name': f,
        'mimeType': mime,
        'parents':   folder_id
    }
    results = service.files().create(
        body=body,
        media_body=MediaFileUpload(f, mimetype=mime, resumable=True)
    ).execute()
```

Comment: Will you be helpful for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43309998/python-w-google-drive-api/43314381#43314381

Comment: thanks... from your example I receive this error: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.html'. Do you know if is it possible to upload a file in base64?

Comment: At this sample, it uploads 'test.html' on current working directory. So if you put it on there, it will be uploaded to Google Drive. Also the base64 files can be uploaded as text/plain.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my Code 2 in the post. I'm getting this error: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable&alt=json returned "Bad Request"> I don't know what I'm sending bad..

Comment: If you want to upload files using service account, please retrieve key file (JSON) console. If you want to upload files using your Google account to Google Drive, please use a sample of Python Quickstart. For both accounts, sample script works fine.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome.  I'm glad to help.